# Ordering entries by custom field (integer)

Tags: templating, entries

I'm new to craft so may it be a basic question, however I can't find an answer for it :-/

I have custom field 'width' in my entry type defined as integer.
What I need to achieve is quite simple:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('windows').find({'width':'> 0'}).order(width) %}
```

The important now is the .order part it's not working right now :-(. What is correct way to do this? I have found some plugins but I believe craft can do this somehow… It always does (so far).

Thanks for any info on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Craft 2

Either of these should work (they are equivalent):

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.width('> 0').section('windows').order('width') %}
```

or

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
  section: 'windows',
  order: 'width',
  width: '> 0'
}) %}
```

The reason you are getting "Array to string conversion" error is that [find](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#find) has turned your [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) into an array.

#### Craft 3

`order` is now `orderBy`

Craft 3 Docs: [Element Queries](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html)

Comment: Yes! Thanks, this really works as it's supposed to, no plugins needed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting in 'width' instead of width?

The order parameter expects a string, not an object, as it just needs to know the name of the field name to filter by.

Final code would look like:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('windows').find({'width':'> 0'}).order('width') %}
```

Comment: Yes, but that ends with „Array to string conversion“ error.Thanks anyway.
In the craft's docs there is written that only textual fields can be used to order. Wierd.
So I have superSort plugin installed… and I can order by width field.
But still believe that craft should do this naturaly. It does with assets.